# js scrollIntoView scrolls all li elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna do something like slot machine 
But the problem is that scrollIntoView scrolls all three list when i pass only 1 list element argument to my scroll method.I think it might be the scrollIntoView fault and i dont know how to repair this.  ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍
‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍
code:

```js
let slot1=document.querySelectorAll(".slot.one>ul>li");
let slot2=document.querySelectorAll(".slot.two>ul>li");
let slot3=document.querySelectorAll(".slot.three>ul>li");
console.log(slot2);
let btn= document.querySelector('.btn');
//console.log(slot1[1].innerHTML)
const animSlots=(asd)=>{
    let rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*(9-1))+1;
  console.log(rand);
    asd.forEach(e=>{
      if(parseInt(e.innerHTML)==rand){
        e.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth',  block:'nearest',inline:'start'})
      }
    })
}
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  animSlots(slot1);
})
```

```css
body{
  background:#2e2e2e;
  color:black;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.slots{
  height:100px;
  width:30%;
  background:white;
  font-size:5rem;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
}
.slot{
  width:33%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
  li{
    height:100px;
  }
  ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
  }
}
@keyframes slots{
  from{top:0px};
  to{top:-800px};
}
```

```html
<div class="slots">
  <div class="slot one">
    <ul>
      <li class="one">1</li>
      <li class="one">2</li>
      <li class="one">3</li>
      <li class="one">4</li>
      <li class="one">5</li>
      <li class="one">6</li>
      <li class="one">7</li>
      <li class="one">8</li>
      <li class="one">9</li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="slot two">
    <ul>
      <li class="two">1</li>
      <li class="two">2</li>
      <li class="two">3</li>
      <li class="two">4</li>
      <li class="two">5</li>
      <li class="two">6</li>
      <li class="two">7</li>
      <li class="two">8</li>
      <li class="two">9</li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="slot three">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>
    
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe will work (in html and css must manipulate).

Html:

```
  <div class="slots">
  <div class="slot one">
    <ul>
      <li class="reone">1</li>
      <li class="reone">2</li>
      <li class="reone">3</li>
      <li class="reone">4</li>
      <li class="reone">5</li>
      <li class="reone">6</li>
      <li class="reone">7</li>
      <li class="reone">8</li>
      <li class="reone">9</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slots">
  <div class="slot two">
    <ul>
      <li class="retwo">1</li>
      <li class="retwo">2</li>
      <li class="retwo">3</li>
      <li class="retwo">4</li>
      <li class="retwo">5</li>
      <li class="retwo">6</li>
      <li class="retwo">7</li>
      <li class="retwo">8</li>
      <li class="retwo">9</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slots">
  <div class="slot three">
    <ul>
      <li class="rethree">1</li>
      <li class="rethree">2</li>
      <li class="rethree">3</li>
      <li class="rethree">4</li>
      <li class="rethree">5</li>
      <li class="rethree">6</li>
      <li class="rethree">7</li>
      <li class="rethree">8</li>
      <li class="rethree">9</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn">click</button>
```

css:

```
         body {
            background: #2e2e2e;
            color: black;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
          }
          .slots {
            height: 100px;
            width: 30%;
            background: white;
            font-size: 5rem;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
          }
```